# How do I open 4 terminal windows and run different commands in each

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

Right now I am trying to build a tunnel for passing files to a sever

But I need to build a tunnel to do this and currently I have to open 4 windows and enter the commands myself

I am wondering if there is a way to run a shell script that opens the 4 terminal window's and enter the right commands in each

I am doing this on a mac using iterm

```
terminal the script is run from - ./Scriptwiththeechos.sh
terminal 1 - echo "1"
terminal 2 - echo "2"
terminal 3 - echo "3"
terminal 4 - echo "4"
```

Thanks for any help u can give, I have found some examples but I cant figure them out

Comment: use `screen` unix tool to do this

Comment: take a look at terminator

Comment: Why do you need four windows instead of four background processes?

Comment: @ccarton i need to build a tunnel to push some files up but the background processess might work can u show me an example ?

Comment: Adding `&` to the end of a command will fork it off in the background. The answers that have already been posted provide some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could achieve it with using a terminating `&` like so:

```
echo "1" &
echo "2" &
echo "3" &
echo "4" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminal emulators such as `xterm` usually have the `-e` option that allows to pass a command and additional arguments, see manpage `xterm(1)`.

You would usually run these terminals as background processes using `&`. If you want them to survive closing your original terminal, you will also need to remove them from your shell's job control using `disown` or `nohup`:

```
xterm -e <commandline1> & disown
xterm -e <commandline2> & disown
xterm -e <commandline3> & disown
xterm -e <commandline4> & disown
```